image!="" in container_cpu_usage_seconds_total metric
This confusion has been bothering me for a while now. I have looked everywhere online, and I couldn't find any consistency of the use of image!="" in container_cpu_usage_seconds_total metric.
Basically, in order to calculate the CPU usage of containers, I found that people either use this:
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[$__rate_interval]))

or this:
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{}[$__rate_interval]))

And there is a huge difference between adding image!="", and not (almost the double).
Could anyone clear this confusion for me? I got an answer from ChatGPT, but I don't want to take it for granted since it makes a lot of mistakes regarding these things.


If you are monitoring the CPU usage for your application containers specifically (excluding system overhead), you should use:
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[$__rate_interval]))

This provides a more accurate representation of your application containers' CPU usage.
If, however, you are interested in all container CPU usage, including system processes, use the broader query:
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{}[$__rate_interval]))

depends on what you want to achieve 1. your application workload cpu or 2. overall cotaniners cpu including system processes
The use of image!="" is essentially filtering out non-application containers, which is why there's a significant difference between the two queries. For application-focused monitoring, image!="" is generally preferred.
